# JS обновление аргумента в url

Tags: javascript, python, django

Пытаюсь реализовать в `python Django` поиск по введенному тексту.
Идея заключается в редиректе через `JS` на страницу `current_page/?search=<текст из input>` при событии `onchange`.
Нижеприведенная функция `search` работает, но в случае повторного запроса получаю `current_page/?search=<текст1>/?search=<текст2>/?...`
В дальнейшем будут и другие аргументы, поэтому есть сомнения о эффективности использования регулярок.

На данный момент выглядит так:
html:

```
...
<div>
    <input id="search__input" type="text" onchange="search(this.value)" placeholder="Поиск...">
</div>
...
```

JS:

```
function search(to) {
    redirect('search', to);
}

function redirect(param_name, to) {
    var url = document.location.href;
    var new_url = url + '?' + param_name + '=' + to + '/';
    window.location.replace(new_url);
}
```

Если есть возможность реализовать это на чистом `JS` или вообще другим способом через `Django`, буду очень рад.

Comment: Что Вам мешает хранить в константе строку `current_page/?search` или в переменной, пока Вы будете делать `var new_url = url + '?' ...` Вы естественно будете получать описанный Вами результат.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему путем передачи дополнительной формы в шаблон:

```
# forms.py

class FilterForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Name', max_length=128, required=False)
```

```
# views.py

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    ...

    filter_form = FilterForm(self.request.GET)

    if filter_form.is_valid():
        name = filter_form.cleaned_data['name']
        new_queryset = Employee.objects.filter(responsible=True)\
        & (Employee.objects.filter(first_name__icontains=name)\
        | Employee.objects.filter(last_name__icontains=name)\
        | Employee.objects.filter(father_name__icontains=name))
    else:
        new_queryset = Employee.objects.filter(responsible=True)
    context['form'].fields['responsible'].queryset = responsible_queryset

    context.update({
        'filter_form': filter_form,
    })

    return context
```

```
# .html

<div>
    <form action="" method="GET">
        {{ select_responsible_form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Найти">
    </form>
</div>
{% for resp in form.fields.responsible.queryset %}
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="id_{{ resp.id }}" value="{{ resp.id }}">
        <label for="id_{{ resp.id }}">
            <option value="{{ resp.id }}">{{ resp }}</option>
        </label>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Спасибо 
[Daniil Loban](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/237463/daniil-loban), что сподвиг меня на это комментарием!)